# Grouping the first two elements in a list of ordered triples

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a long list of the form

```
{{0.005, 1.05, 1.*10^-20}, {0.015, 1.05, 1.*10^-20}, {0.025, 1.05, 
  1.*10^-20}, {0.035, 1.05, 1.*10^-20}, {0.045, 1.05, 
  1.*10^-20}, {0.055, 1.05, 1.*10^-20}, {0.065, 1.05, 
  1.*10^-20}, ........, {3.505, -0.95, 1.*10^-20}}
```

The first two elements in each list item are coordinates, the third is a function value at those coordinates. I want to do an interpolation so that I can get the function value also at points in between the given coordinates. For that I need to reorder the list into the form

```
{{{0.005, 1.05}, 1.*10^-20}, {{0.015, 1.05}, 
  1.*10^-20}, {{0.025, 1.05}, 1.*10^-20}, {{0.035, 1.05}, 
  1.*10^-20}, {{0.045, 1.05}, 1.*10^-20}, {{0.055, 1.05}, 
  1.*10^-20}, {{0.065, 1.05}, 1.*10^-20},.......
```

so that the coordinates are always grouped together. How do I do this best in *Mathematica*?

Comment: `{{#1, #2}, #3} & @@@ list`.

Comment: ...or `list /. {x_, y_, z_} -> {{x, y}, z}` ;-)

Comment: or... `Transpose[{list[[All, 1 ;; 2]], list[[All, 3]]}]`

Comment: ... or `{#[[1 ;; 2]], #[[3]]} & /@ list` (similar to my first one and @eldo's).

Comment: Or `{Most@#, Last@#}&/@list ` or `Through[{Most, Last} [list]] `

Comment: Anyone feel like writing an answer here summarizing these answers? P.S. I don't really agree with the close-vote. While the question is simple to answer, I don't think there's a *direct* answer in the documentation (or at least one that's easy to find). And while the question might appear relatively localized, the original format is a standard data format, but the output format is required for `Interpolation`, so I feel like this question is relevant for a lot of situations.

Comment: My suggestion with `Through` has somewhat inaccurate syntax. Correcting it in the answer below now.

Comment: No one has remarked on the fact that you do **not** need to format the data like this to use `Interpolation`. You can just give it triplets like `{x,y,f[x,y]}` and it will return the appropriate interpolating function.

Comment: @JasonB true, but undocumented and, IIRC, formerly not possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is to summarize the methods given in the comments.

march

```
{{#1, #2}, #3} & @@@ list

{#[[1 ;; 2]], #[[3]]} & /@ list
```

mgamer

```
list /. {x_, y_, z_} -> {{x, y}, z}
```

eldo

```
Transpose[{list[[All, 1 ;; 2]], list[[All, 3]]}]
```

LLlAMnYP

```
{Most @ #, Last @ #}& /@ list

Through@*{Most, Last} /@ list

Through[{Most, Last}[#]] & /@ list
```

m_goldberg

```
Thread[{list[[All, {1, 2}]], list[[All, 3]]}]

TakeDrop[#, 2]& /@ list
```

$\qquad$ `TakeDrop` is better than `Thread` because it scans the list only once.

JasonB:

```
(* Don't bother reframing the list*)
Interpolation[list]
(* works just fine when list={{x1,y1,f[x1,y1]},{x2,y2,f[x2,y2]}...} *)
```

Comment: I liked mgamer's simple solution which worked. Of course, JasonB's is even simpler, but there is nothing about this in the Wolfram Docu.