# How to restructure a list of {x,y,f[x,y]}-triples for use with Interpolation?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have lists of triples `{{x1, y1, f[x1,y1]},{x2, y2, f[x2,y2]},... }`, which I would like to interpolate. In order to use Interpolation[], I seem to need a list structure such as `{{{x1, y1}, f[x1,y1]},{{x2, y2}, f[x2,y2]},...}`. How can I convert the original lists to the required new structure? Is there an alternative way of using Interpolation[] on the original lists?

Comment: Apparently [an identical question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98090/484) was closed(?!) two months ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can restructure your input easily enough...

```
data = {{x1, y1, f11}, ... {xm,yn,fmn}};

Interpolation[ { {#[[1]],#[[2]]}, #[[3]] } & /@ data, ...];
```

If you're *computing* `f[xi,yj]` instead of retrieving it from elsewhere, it would be better to do this at the source:

```
arguments = {{x1,y1}, ..., {xm,yn}};
data = {#, f@@# } & /@ arguments;
(*  or 
  data = ParallelMap[ {#, f@@# } & , arguments ];
if the computation is not trivial and small time is more important 
than small memory  *)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map a pure function over the list to restructure it.

```
list = {{x1, y1, f[x1, y1]}, {x2, y2, f[x2, y2]}};

{#[[1 ;; 2]], #[[3]]} & /@ list
(* {{{x1, y1}, f[x1, y1]}, {{x2, y2}, f[x2, y2]}} *)
```

Hope this helps.